# How can I make a text input only as wide as its parent div, without specifying an explicit width?

Tags: html, css, textbox, html-input

I have a container div with two child divs, one being a textbox, and the other being a label below it, like this:

```
.container { display:inline-block; }

<div class="container">
  <div class="input-container"><input type="text" /></div>
  <div class="label">Some text here</div>
</div>
```

I would like the container to be only as wide as needed to fit the label div in, and I would like the textbox to be the same width.

If I use an explicit width for the container, I can set `width:100%` for the input and it works fine. However, this isn't an option because my content will vary in width.

No matter what I do, the textbox seems to have a minimum width that it "wants" to be, so the whole container gets propped open.

How can I make the input only as wide as the containing div, whose width is shrink-wrapped to match the text? In other words, in the example above, I want the text "Some text here" to dictate how wide the textbox and container are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea to set position absolute and set 100% width on the input box, so it always get same width based on the length of the label text.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/43jm73gs/1/

```
.container {
    display:inline-block;
}

.input-container {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.input-container:after {
    content: "\00a0"; /*&nbsp;*/
}

.input-container input {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I wanted to do this without resorting to javascript layout hacks. This is perfect. Just one question -- It seems to work just fine even without the .input-container:after CSS. What is that doing?

Comment: Because making the input position absolute which also making the container collapses, but placing a pseudo content inside can prevent that to happen. Or to set a minimum fixed height to container is also fine - http://jsfiddle.net/43jm73gs/3/ I can see what you were trying on /2, also take a look of this http://jsfiddle.net/43jm73gs/4/ I'm sure you'll get the point.

Comment: Ah, I see. I had used enough margin-bottom that it had the same effect as using margin plus explicit height. This is great. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

At first, parent div needs its width.

then there's two options.

1. 

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="input-container" style="width:200px"><input type="text" style="width:100%"/></div>
    <div class="label">Some text here</div>
</div>
```

2. 

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="input-container" style="width:200px"><input id="input-box" type="text" /></div>
    <div class="label">Some text here</div>
</div>
<script>
    var parentWidth = document.getElementsByClassName("input-container")[0].style.width;
    document.getElementById("input-box").style.width = parentWidth;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery I'd do the following:

```js
$('.label').each(function() {
  //get width of label
  var labelWidth = $(this).width();
  //apply that width to the input before it
  $(this).prev().children('input').css('width', labelWidth);
});
```

```css
.container {

  display: inline-block;

}

.label {

  white-space: nowrap;

  display: inline-block;

}

.container input {

  display: block;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="label">Some text here</div>
</div>
```